# Minimizing Console Screen

Tags: c

so I made a C program that imitates a ATM except you can create bank accounts in it.  But when the user quits the application, the application loses all values, so they have to recreate the account, and redo all their settings.

I have tried to look this up by Googling it and consulting C programming books but I haven't found anything. So is there any code to minimize the console screen from within the program so that the application doesn't actually close and lose all the values? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you really want just to minimize window? Wouldn't be better to save state of your 'ATM' into a file (database, ...) at exit and load it on start?

Comment: I know that I could use a database but I was wondering if I could minimize the screen anyway.

Comment: As @ Shukla Jay said above.. if you don't want to use DB use FILE handling concept. In this whenever you exit from your application all the data is save in your file.

Comment: Just tell the user to minimise the window instead of closing it. Or do you want the data to persist between program runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want **to minimize the console window** you have to:

1. `#include <Windows.h>`
2. Use the block below:

   ```
   /* the following code minimizes the console window */
   {
       char szTitle[256];    
       HWND hConsole = NULL;    

       memset(szTitle, 0, sizeof(szTitle));

       /* get the console window's title */
       GetConsoleTitle((LPWSTR)szTitle, 256);

       /* get the HWND windows handle of the console window by looking up for 
          windows with szTitle as title*/
       hConsole = FindWindow(NULL, (LPWSTR)szTitle );

       /* "show" it as minimzed */
       ShowWindow(hConsole, SW_MINIMIZE);
   }
   ```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

it's called Database. you can save all your records into a file(any kind you want) and you need to read that file when application start and build your data set.

for example:

if you have a record for each account containing `name`, `id`, `balance`, then you can save before closing to a normal .txt, say "C:\tmp\DB.txt" file all the records as ,,* string for each record.

upon entering the application you'll check if a file "C:\tmp\DB.txt" exist and if so read it and build the data accordingly.

back to your question. it is possible to just minimize the program when pressing the close button in winforms for windows and in other ways for other languages. It might be possible to do it in c, though i doubt it. anyway it makes no sense, because the user can still kill the process despite your efforts and thus make it not worthwhile to do it

Comment: it would be better if he use sqlite...isn`t it??

Comment: @Krishna maybe, i'm not here to recommend, just give an example. give one too and i'll give you my +1 if it's good

Comment: Actually you can recommend if he will get some knowledge by that.